# How to check umask for all users under Linux?

Tags: umask

Under AIX I can check the `umask` for all users with:

```
cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd | while read ONELINE; do lsuser -a umask "$ONELINE"; done
```

But how can I check the `umask` setting for all users under Linux? (`su` to every user and then `umask` command? Are there any better ways for it?)

**UPDATE1:**

It's not the best to `su` to all users, because on some RHEL servers the default shell for a few user is halt/shutdown..:

```
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown;asdf;asdf;F:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
```

so if I `su` to the user... then the server shuts down?

**UPDATE2:** I created a bounty for a non-su based answer.

Comment: I have already mentioned for avoid system user ($3 > 500), means check above UID 500

Comment: again: I need to check umask for **all** users, not excluding system users :)

Comment: we can check for valid shell, what you think ? , means if shell is other that /bin/bash , then we can skip that user. isn't it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check using (execute as root) :

```
for user in $(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd); 
do 
    printf "%-10s" "$user" ; su -c 'umask' -l $user 2>/dev/null
done
```

To avoid checking system user do :

```
for user in $(awk -F: '( $3 >= 500 ){print $1}' /etc/passwd); 
do 
    printf "%-10s" "$user" ; su -c 'umask' -l $user 2>/dev/null
done
```

**OutPut:**

```
ram       0022
shyam     0022
suraj     0022
vinayak   0022
javed     0022
```

Comment: ok, thanks, but are there any ways to check the umask without "su"ing to the user?

Comment: if you have manually set , say in `~.bashrc` then you can grep into this file.

Comment: It could be set in many places... that's why grepping is not the best solution

Comment: then we have to check in many place

Comment: it should be better , if you have set umask in per user in common file eg .bashrc

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, your first script outputs the word "root" and then freezes for me.

Comment: Freezing happened to me as well, looks like it expects some input. Hitting enter twice got it to print the next user... over and over again.

Answer (score 15):

The `umask` is typically set system wide through the config file: `/etc/login.defs`:

```
$ grep UMASK /etc/login.defs 
UMASK           077
```

This value can be overridden but typically is not through either `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and/or by the users in their `$HOME/.bashrc` (Assuming they're using Bash).

If you `grep` for "umask" in those aforementioned files you'll also notice this on RHEL boxes:

```
$ grep umask /etc/bashrc /etc/profile
/etc/bashrc:    # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
/etc/bashrc:       umask 002
/etc/bashrc:       umask 022
/etc/profile:# By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for login shell
/etc/profile:    umask 002
/etc/profile:    umask 022
```

Digging deeper:

- `/etc/bashrc`

  ```
  # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
  # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
  # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
  # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
  if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
     umask 002
  else
     umask 022
  fi
  ```
- `/etc/profile`

  ```
  # By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for login shell
  # Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
  # You could check uidgid reservation validity in
  # /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
  if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`id -gn`" = "`id -un`" ]; then
      umask 002
  else
      umask 022
  fi
  ```

So at least on RHEL system's the `umask` is either `002` if your UID is greater than 199, and `022` otherwise (system accounts).

Comment: For Ubuntu and (probably) Debian-based systems, you should do this in `~/.profile`, which has the default value commented at the top of the file for you to uncomment and modify on a per-user basis.